# Populating cells with maximum from range of cells in another row

Tags: excel

I need to populate a range of cells in one row from the maximum in a range from another row. My range is defined by an integer, in this case 4.

Example:

Row 1:

```
206 0 0 0 238 0 0 0 251 0 0 0 265
```

I need the second row to be:

```
206 238 238 238 238 251 251 251 251 265 265 265 265.
```

I've tried `INDIRECT`, `COUNT`, and others with no luck.

Comment: Can't you just do `=MAX(A1:D1)` for cell `A2`?

Comment: Will there always be three zeros between each number? If so, you can just use `=Sum(A2:A5)` and pull it across.

Comment: Jordan, I tried this, however, the "three" in the "three zeros" value in the example above is a variable and will be changing for each row. I keep running to the situation where it seems like I need to assemble a cell address using the variable.